# How to execute an update query?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oraclecommand

I know how I do this, I have actually done it before, but the following code HANGS (not throw an exception) in this update statement below, and I don't see a reason for it. Can anyone see why?

I don't think is important but `id` is the primary key of `Person` and `belongs` is a foreign key.

Before any sugest concurrence problem, I am the only person working on the tables.
The creation of the command is so:

```
public static String upDatePersonBelonging(Int32 personId,Int32 groupId)
{
    String error;
    if ((error = openConnection()) != "")
        return error;

    OracleCommand command = 
      new OracleCommand("UPDATE person SET belongs = :belongs where id = :id ",
                         connection);

    addParameter(command, "belongs", OracleDbType.Int32, groupId);
    addParameter(command, "id", OracleDbType.Int32, personId);

    return runCommand(command);
}
```

The execution is so:

```
private static String runCommand(OracleCommand command)
{
    String error = "";

    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // here it hangs
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        error = e.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    return error;
}
```

The opening function is the following:

```
private static String openConnection()
{
    try
    {
        // create an open the connection          
        connection = new OracleConnection(_connStr);

        // open the connection
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }

    return "";
}
```

add parameter code:

```
private static void addParameter(OracleCommand command, String name, OracleDbType type, Object value)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(name, type);
    command.Parameters[command.Parameters.Count-1] = new OracleParameter(name, value);
}
```

Comment: can you update the table using SQLPlus (logged on as the same user as in your connection string)?

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes I can update de table in SQLDevloper and SQL plus. And yes I debug it and hangs there, and not show any more, like if get in an infinit loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems to be correct.

I have 3 ideas:

1. Update can be very long operation if there are many rows in the table and simply you have to wait (you can do this query using some other code/tool and compare times).
2. Show as `addParameter` method.
3. Maybe some other process is working on this table and locks it.

**EDIT**

Your `addParameter` method is strange. First you add parameter and then create new one.
I will try rather something like this (not tested - I have no possibility):

```
private static void addParameter(OracleCommand command, String name,
  OracleDbType type, Object value)
{
    OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(name, value);
    p.DbType = type;
    command.Parameters.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: 1 and 3 are not and 2 I dont understand it

Comment: HAHAHAHA the reason is because before I was using other Command not OrcleCommand, I was using OleDBCommand and work a lite bit different. The form is strange, but without parallelism works ;)

Comment: @user1739342 Have it helped?

Comment: I know it work with other updates sentences, and just for this one not. Any why you want I test it?

Comment: @user1739342 I just wanted to know wheter my answer was solution to your problem, because from your comments I can't understand it. If it was an solution then you can mark my post as an answer. If no you can post your own solution - final code.

Comment: mmmm... this is strange, I check it with again, just in case, if the all way of doing it, I mean how is in the question, and know dont hang. I just uncomented what was before. Sorry I have no idea what was the problem :/